# How do I match ini file keys that may not contain an equal sign?

Tags: regex, powershell, ini

I am using the following Powershell code (modified version of https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ea40c1ef-c856-434b-b8fb-ebd7a76e8d91) to parse an ini file:

```
$ini = @{} 
$lastSection = "" 
    switch -regex -file $FilePath  
    {  
        "^\[(.+)\]$" # Section  
        {  
            $section = $matches[1]  
            $ini[$section] = @{}  
            $CommentCount = 0  
            $lastSection = $section
            Continue
        }  
        "^(;.*)$" # Comment  
        {  
            $section = "Comments"
            if ($ini[$section] -eq $null)
            {
                $ini[$section] = @{}
            } 
            $value = $matches[1]  
            $CommentCount = $CommentCount + 1  
            $name = "Comment" + $CommentCount  
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value
            $section = $lastSection 
            Continue
        }   
        "(.+?)\s*=\s*(.*)" # Key  
        {  
            if (!($section))  
            {  
                $section = "No-Section"  
                $ini[$section] = @{}  
            }  
            $name,$value = $matches[1..2]  
            $ini[$section][$name] = $value  
            Continue
        }  
        "([A-Z])\w+\s+" # Key  
        {  
            if (!($section))  
            {  
                $section = "No-Section"  
                $ini[$section] = @{}  
            }  
            $value = $matches[1]  
            $ini[$section][$value] = $value  
        }
    }
```

Ini files that I deal with can contain keys that have an equal sign, and some that do not. For example:

```
[Cipher]
OpenSSL

[SSL]
CertFile=file.crt
```

The switch statement correctly matches the `CertFile=file.crt` line and I was hoping that the last `"([A-Z])\w+\s+"` condition would catch the `OpenSSL` line. However it does not, and I have not been able to figure out what regex I can use to catch those lines where the key does not contain an equal sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to match **at least one whitespace** character with `\s+`

You could use part of the regex you already have for matching the lines with `=`.

```
"(.+?)\s*"
```

Consider anchoring your strings too in order the match the full line so
it becomes

```
"^(.+?)\s*$"
```

Comment: Reusing the first part of the previous regex plus the anchoring (`"^(.+?)\s*$"`) did work for me. I should note that it was not working correctly until I added the anchoring. Without anchoring, `$matches[1]` was just "O" but once I added the anchoring, it matched the full string. Thanks!